# 'TypeConverter' does not contain a definition for 'IsValid' in MVC6

Tags: visual-studio-2005, asp.net-core-mvc

i am using MVC 6 and i have referred the following name space,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Syncfusion.JavaScript.Shared.Serializer;
using System.Reflection;
```

here is my code,

```
static bool CanConvertTo<T>(string s)  {
   TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
   return converter.IsValid(s);
}
```

it throw the error like this,

'TypeConverter' does not contain a definition for 'IsValid' and no extension method 'IsValid' accepting a first argument of type 'TypeConverter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**this was reproduced only in MVC6**

how to resolve this and there is any alternate solution for this?

[image: Project.JSON]

Comment: Could you provide dependencies from `project.json`?

Comment: I tried your example code in MVC 6 (beta 7). The compiler has no problems with the method "IsValid". Could you show me `dependencies` section of you `project.json`. May be some dependencies are missing in your project.

Comment: i have added project.json screenshot please find it

Answer (score 0):

There is `IsValid` method in `System, Version=4.0.0.0`:

```
namespace System.ComponentModel
{
    public class TypeConverter
    {
        // other members

        public bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            // some implementation
        }
    }
}
```

There are two frameworks in your configuration: `dnx451` and `dnxcore50`. I'm not sure the method `IsValid` exists in `dnxcore50`.

If you use only `dnx451` framework, I recommend you try it:

1) Switch the project framework to `dnx451` (or delete `dnxcore50` section from `project.json`). If it's useless then:

2) Update the project to `MVC 6 beta 7` and use next configuration in `project.jso`n:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta7"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  }
```

I tried your example code in a project with this configuration and there are not any problems. My solution DNX SDK version is `1.0.0-beta7`.

Comment: Thanks for u r reply.. in dnx451 is working fine but i am using dnxcore50